RealSense R200 Camera Not Detected on Windows 10
I have a RealSense R200 camera, and when I connect it to my Windows 10 machine, it appears in the Device Manager like this:

I'm not entirely sure about the exact model of the camera, but here's a photo of it:

I tried using the following Python code to access the camera streams, but it returns "No device found":
import pyrealsense2 as rs
import numpy as np
import cv2

pipeline = rs.pipeline()

config = rs.config()
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 640, 480, rs.format.z16, 30)
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 640, 480, rs.format.bgr8, 30)

pipeline.start(config)

Additionally, the RealSense Viewer v2.34.0 is unable to connect to the camera.
Could you please advise on how I can successfully access the camera streams?
